# New line character not appearing correctly in matplotlib annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `plt.annotate` with a string that looks like: `"br: 147\nhealthy: 0\n ..."` but the new line characters appear as square boxes in the plot. Does anyone have a solution to this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a special font? Which version of matplotlib is this?

Comment: No special font as far as I know, I've not changed any text-related options at all. This is matplotlib 3.1.0.

Comment: Ah I've fixed it - I miscopied and in fact I was using "\r\n" rather than just "\n". Removing the "\r" fixed it.